# How to tell what version of puppet you are running on centos?

Tags: centos, puppet

I'm getting started with puppet on centos and was confused about a few things.  First off a man page exists for `puppet-master` but not for `puppetmaster` even though the daemon in /etc/init.d is `puppetmaster`

Running the command `$ puppet-master --version` returns bash: puppet-master: command not found.

How do I tell what version I am running for both the master and the client?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Newer versions of puppet use a slightly different command line.  The command you are looking for would be `puppet --version`, `puppet master --version`, and `puppet agent --version`

For versions before 4.0, if puppet was installed as an RPM package you can query the RPM database like `rpm -qa | grep puppet`.  For Debian/Ubuntu/Mint fans, the package query is `dpkg -l | grep puppet`.

Puppetlabs has changed their packaging and the packaged puppet version is no indicated by the version number of the puppet-agent package.

Comment: Is the hyphen for pre 2.6 version? Also do the master and agent need to be running the same major version?

Comment: I'm not sure when they made the change.  With version 3 Puppet Labs commited to using semantic versioning.  This means that major version number changes indicate a change that breaks backwards compatibility.  You should be OK if you have a mix of 3.x.y.  I wouldn't try a mix of 2.x and 3.x without testing that the results match my expectations.

Comment: I've done a little more testing and have found that I can use a 2.7 puppet agent with a 3.2.x puppet server.

Answer (score 4):

```
root@puppet01 ~:
# puppet --version
3.2.2
root@puppet01 ~:
# puppet master --version
3.2.2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# rpm -qa | grep puppet
puppet-server-2.6.18-3.el6.noarch
puppet-2.6.18-3.el6.noarch
```

first line is version of the server side, the second - client side

```
# puppet agent --version
2.6.18

# puppet master --version
2.6.18
```

works too

Answer (score 0):

For the fun, you can also use Puppet!

```
puppet apply -e 'notice("$clientversion")'
```

Also, in a manifest on the Puppet master, you can add such line:

```
fail("Server version: $serverversion, Client version: $clientversion")'
fail(inline_template("<%=clientversion.split('.')[0]%>"))
```

(Note that `$serverversion` is empty when using `puppet apply`)

Answer (score 0):

Installed the puppet on ubuntu 18.04 , got the same error , the puppet command doesn't get added to the path  hence this error

navigated to this path /opt/puppetlabs/bin and run the command puppet master --version

you get the desired result